# Laravel - Method [validate] does not exist on Redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I know this question has been asked a lot of times on stackoverflow, but everyone I could find did not help me. Whenever I try to register a user, that has something invalid (email already registered, password not long enough etc.) I get the message in the title.

My RegisterController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $validator =  Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'lastname' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails())
        {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }

        return $validator;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $confirmation_code = str_random(30);


        Mail::send('user.verify', ['code' => $confirmation_code], function($message) {
            $message->to(Input::get('email'), Input::get('username'))
                ->subject('Verify your email address');
        });


//        Flash::message('Thanks for signing up! Please check your email.');

        $user =  new User;
        $user->lastname = $data['lastname'];
        $user->name = $data['name'];
        $user->email = $data['email'];
        $user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);
        $user->confirmation_code = $confirmation_code;
        $user->save();


        return $user;
    }


}
```

I need help, I hope someone can help with this issue. If any other classes are needed, I'll be glad to provide them.

Edit: Updated, since I noticed the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The validator method should return a Validator. The error you see is because you return a Redirect response, and some code presumes you return a Validator and calls $validator->validate() on it.

You need to throw an HttpResponseException instead. Your exception handler should catch these and render the response accordingly; in this case perform the redirect.